# How to Use Functions properly with GUI and netmiko

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, netmiko

I'm new for Programming and right now doing a small project for my Network Engineer job.

The whole idea of this app: input IP, MAC, username, password: and see prints from functions like:

**logging to device!**
**gathering info**
**and etc**

and show all this info real time in **print_out = tkinter.Text** box

Currently, I have 2 .py files:
**MAC_search_GUI.py**
**MAC_search.py**

**MAC_search_GUI.py** is a **tkinter**  window where I can put in **IP**, **MAC**, **username**, and **password** + there is another window where I can see logs:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import Button, Text
from tkinter import simpledialog
from MAC_search import MAC_search_func

def show_entry_fields():
    IP = e1.get()
    MAC = e2.get()
    username = e3.get()
    password = e4.get()

    """
    e1.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    e2.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    e3.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    e4.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    """

    SESSION = {'ip': IP, 
                'device_type':'cisco_ios', 
                'username': username,
                'password': password}
    
    result = MAC_search_func(IP, MAC, **SESSION)
    return print(result)

#   f4b5.2fa0.8fca

root = tkinter.Tk()

tkinter.Label(root, text="IP:").grid(row=1)
tkinter.Label(root, text="MAC:").grid(row=2)
tkinter.Label(root, text="Username").grid(row=3)
tkinter.Label(root, text="Password").grid(row=4)

e1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
e2 = tkinter.Entry(root)
e3 = tkinter.Entry(root)
e4 = tkinter.Entry(root)

e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
e3.grid(row=3, column=1)
e4.grid(row=4, column=1)


print_out = tkinter.Text(root, height = 20,  width = 60,  bg = "light cyan").grid(row=7, column=2)

tkinter.Button(root, text='Apply', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=tkinter.W, 
pady=4)

root.geometry("600x600")

root.mainloop()
```

The function **MAC_search_func** is located in **MAC_search.py**, connecting to input IP and collecting info about that device:

```
import netmiko 
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoAuthenticationException
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException



def MAC_search_func(arg_ip, arg_mac, **arg_session):


    def conv_Po_to_Int(arg_int):
        JSON = connection.send_command("show etherchannel summary", use_textfsm=True)   
        for line in JSON: 
            if line['po_name'] == arg_int:
                int_status = line['interfaces']
        return int_status[0]


    interface = ''

    try: 
        connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**arg_session)                         
        print("Connection is succefull")
    except NetMikoTimeoutException:                                             
        return print(" ####  Device is not reachable!  ####")
    except NetMikoAuthenticationException:                                      
        return print(" ####  Wrong Username or Password!  ####") 
    except SSHException:                                                        
        return print(" ####  Make sure SSH is enabled!  ####")
    
    # Looking for MAC in Mac address table 
    JSON = connection.send_command("show mac address-table", use_textfsm=True)       
    for line in JSON: 
        if line['destination_address'] == arg_mac:
            interface = line['destination_port']
            # Checking if interface is Port channel 
            if interface[0:2] == "Po":
                interface = conv_Po_to_Int(interface)

    # IF MAC is not found 
    if interface == '':
        return print("This MAC-ADDRESS IS NOT FOUND ON THIS IP: "+ arg_ip)



    # If Mac was found on switch checking if Int is Trunk or Access
    JSON = connection.send_command("show interfaces status", use_textfsm=True) 
    for line in JSON: 
        if line['port'] == interface:
            int_status = line['vlan']


    # if port is trunk checking which device located on another end
    if int_status == "trunk":
        JSON = connection.send_command("show cdp neighbors " + interface, use_textfsm=True) 
        for line in JSON:
            next_switch = line['neighbor']
        JSON = connection.send_command("show cdp entry " + next_switch) 
        result = JSON.find('IP address:') 
        return print("Looks like this mac located on device with " + JSON[result:(result  + 21)] + " and hostname: " + next_switch) 
    else:
        return print("MAC was found on " + interface) 

    connection.disconnect()
```

So, I have a few issues with that:

1. I don't know how to send **RETURN** from my **MAC_searc**h function back to **MAC_search_GUI**, so I can print it with:

   ```
     print_out = tkinter.Text(root, height = 20,  width = 60,  bg = "light cyan").grid(row=7, column=2)
   ```
2. When I pressing **Apply**, the app is NOt-responding until all functions will not be finished(5-10 seconds), because it takes time to connect and get info from switch. How to make that after i will click **Apply**, app will not wait until the end but just continue working, until **Return** will not show up in **print_out** window

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Mast,

Solution is:

1. for my first problem:

   ```
          result = MAC_search_func(IP, MAC, **SESSION)
          return print_out.insert("end-1c", result)
   ```
2. For my second problem I did not found complete solution, but it working faster now.